# tradução no menu do rodapé

Tags: debate, tradução

No rodapé do site tem esses links:
tour ajuda blog bate-papo.. bababa..

Um dos links está como "móvel", provavelmente traduzido de "mobile".

Não seria melhor manter "mobile" ? ou "versão mobile".

Parece meio bobo perguntar isso, mas enfim, perguntei. rsrs

Comment: Concordo. Antes de fazer a mudança (é só alterar [3 strings no Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/40270544?qt=m%C3%B3vel)), só gostaria de saber a opinião dos portugueses.

Comment: Eu prefiro "versão mobile" ou "mobile".

Comment: "Não podem ser criadas novas tags a partir da versão mobile do site . As tags '$tags$' são novas."

Comment: @JorgeB. Então vocês dizem igual à gente. Às vezes eu vejo pessoas dizerem "móvel", mas a maioria diz "mobile" mesmo.

Comment: Mas nos dizemos e pronunciamos "mobile" como em Inglês, ai também é assim? "môbail"